# Home Debian install no longer boots

Tags: boot, 64-bit, debian

After almost a year of working wonderfully, my home computer has suddenly stopped. I thought it was a thermal issue: from cold I could login and even maybe start firefox before it would freeze (screen became static, network died, etc.) but if I rebooted after that it would stop much earlier. Today it has become much more consistent: booting recovery (verbose) mode always gets up through: "[xxx] devtmpfs: initialized" and then hangs.

Things that work:

> memtest86+ runs fine and reports no errors.
>   Grub always loads and stays loaded fine.
>   A Debian 32bit install (rescue) disk loaded and did not crash.

Things that don't work:

> 64bit Debian install on the main HD
>   A 64bit Debian install disk I burned today did not load past the menu.

Could the debian amd64 bit kernel not be correctly built for my computer? Any advice would be much appreciated!

System:

> MB: MSI 890FXA-GD70
>   CPU: AMD FX 8120
>   RAM: Kingston
>   HyperX 2x4GB
>   VID: EVGA GTX550Ti
>   Root HD: OCZ 30GB SATA II SSD

Comment: It's definitely a hardware problem and you'll need to weed through the logs to really know. IMHO, time to buy a $300 new PC and move your HDD over to it. When a "works everyday linux computer" stops working, it's the hardware.

Comment: Though I agree with @ChrisK, try booting the 32 bit CD and look at the logs, specifically `/var/log/kern.log`,`/var/log/boot`,`/var/log/pm-powersave.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. Update your question with any new info and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Open it up, check for excess dust and duff fans.